# Best way to demonstrate how easy it is to crack your password

Tags: passwords

stackoverflow community.
I am currently a middle school computer science teacher. 
I was wondering what was the best tool to demonstrate how easy it is to crack their password. (could be a program that I can install)

I want each students to enter what they think is a "hard" password and the rainbowtable will solve it and display the time/password. (I've done my research and looked at rainbow tables)

Hopefully this community can help me :)

Thank you in advance.

P.s sorry if this question isn't posted in the correct location.

Answer (score 2):

Well...I'm not going to touch password cracking algorithms with a 10 foot pole, even for an academic discussion.

But, you could demonstrate using sleight of hand by putting a packet sniffer such as wireshark (or ethereal) between the hosts and an LDAP server and just capture each of their passwords in clear text on their way down.

You could also install a keystroke logger on each of the machines and just have it simply log their passwords to a file.

Either would be "cheating", but that's another valuable point that you could make. It really doesn't matter how strong your password is if someone can get access to it.  The usual way that people get access to other peoples' sensitive data is through sleight of hand and deception, not brute force.

Brute force, such as rainbow tabling a hash can still be used, of course "to break through the front door." But, if someone "leaves the window open", why go through the trouble and take the conspicuous route?

(P.S. I personally think it's unwise to be discussing cryptographic attack methods in a middle school setting. If you are going to do this at all, I think it would be **very dangerous** to expose the method you used. I wouldn't mention the method to any of your students at all or I guarantee you are going to inspire several of them to go running amok)